# React-howler plays audio at slightly different speeds in different browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, howler.js

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution to this. I'm loading audio in at a specific point using the React Howler player. After about 20 minutes of audio, it becomes clear that the audio is out of sync in Chrome compared to Firefox and Safari (which are the same). You can try it here: https://search-prototype-gray.vercel.app/. If you play audio in Chrome, it will start in a different place than Safari and Firefox, even through the timestamps are accurate. This is also true for just playing or moving the seek bar.

This is making me crazy! If anyone has experience with cross-browser audio timing weirdness and can help I'd be very very grateful.

My code is the [full control code](https://khoanguyen.me/react-howler/). Find it below as well:

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      preload: false,
      loaded: false,
      loop: false,
      mute: false,
      volume: 1.0,
      seek: 0,
      rate: 1,
      isSeeking: false
    }
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this)
    this.handleOnLoad = this.handleOnLoad.bind(this)
    this.handleOnEnd = this.handleOnEnd.bind(this)
    this.handleOnPlay = this.handleOnPlay.bind(this)
    this.handleStop = this.handleStop.bind(this)
    this.renderSeekPos = this.renderSeekPos.bind(this)
    this.handleLoopToggle = this.handleLoopToggle.bind(this)
    this.handleMuteToggle = this.handleMuteToggle.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseDownSeek = this.handleMouseDownSeek.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseUpSeek = this.handleMouseUpSeek.bind(this)
    this.handleSeekingChange = this.handleSeekingChange.bind(this)
    this.handleRate = this.handleRate.bind(this)
    this.resetRecording = this.resetRecording.bind(this)
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.clearRAF()
  }

  handleToggle () {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    })
  }

  resetRecording () {
    this.setState({
      playing: false
    })
    this.player.seek(this.props.startTime)
    this.renderSeekPos()
  }

  handleOnLoad () {
    this.setState({
      loaded: true,
      duration: this.player.duration()
    })
    this.player.seek(this.props.startTime)
  }

  handleOnPlay () {
    this.setState({
      playing: true
    })
    this.renderSeekPos()
  }

  handleOnEnd () {
    this.setState({
      playing: false
    })
    this.clearRAF()
  }

  handleStop () {
    this.player.stop()
    this.setState({
      playing: false // Need to update our local state so we don't immediately invoke autoplay
    })
    this.renderSeekPos()
  }

  handleLoopToggle () {
    this.setState({
      loop: !this.state.loop
    })
  }

  handleMuteToggle () {
    this.setState({
      mute: !this.state.mute
    })
  }

  handleMouseDownSeek () {
    this.setState({
      playing: false,
      isSeeking: true
    })
  }

  handleMouseUpSeek (e) {
    this.setState({
      isSeeking: false
    })

    this.player.seek(e.target.value)
  }

  handleSeekingChange (e) {
    this.setState({
      seek: parseFloat(e.target.value)
    })
  }

  renderSeekPos () {
    if (!this.state.isSeeking) {
      this.setState({
        seek: this.player.seek()
      })
    }
    if (this.state.playing) {
      this._raf = raf(this.renderSeekPos)
    }
  }

  handleRate (e) {
    const rate = parseFloat(e.target.value)
    this.player.rate(rate)
    this.setState({ rate })
  }

  clearRAF () {
    raf.cancel(this._raf)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='full-control'>
        <ReactHowler
          src={[this.props.recording]}
          preload={this.state.preload}
          playing={this.state.playing}
          onLoad={this.handleOnLoad}
          onPlay={this.handleOnPlay}
          onEnd={this.handleOnEnd}
          loop={this.state.loop}
          mute={this.state.mute}
          volume={this.state.volume}
          seek={this.state.seek}
          rate={this.state.rate}
          ref={(ref) => (this.player = ref)}
        />

        {this.state.loaded &&
        <div>
          <Button onClick={this.handleToggle}>
            {(this.state.playing) ? <FaPause /> : <FaPlay />}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.resetRecording}>
            <BiReset/>
          </Button>
        </div>
        }

        {!this.state.loaded &&
        <Button onClick={this.handleToggle}>
          {(this.state.playing) ? <BiLoader /> : <FaPlay />}
        </Button>
        }

        {this.state.loaded &&
        <p className="timeline">
          {new Date(this.state.seek.toFixed(0) * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)}
          {' / '}
          {(this.state.duration) ? new Date(this.state.duration.toFixed(0) * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) : 'NaN'}
        </p>
        }

        <div className='seek'>
          <span className='slider-container'>
            <input
              type='range'
              min='0'
              max={this.state.duration ? this.state.duration.toFixed(2) : 0}
              step='.01'
              value={this.state.seek}
              onChange={this.handleSeekingChange}
              onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDownSeek}
              onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUpSeek}
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Player
```